# Why the generalized root test for series does not use $\liminf$ to get rid of the inconclusive part?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, soft-question

I wonder for what reasons the generalized root test for series (Roughly: $\limsup a_{n}^{1/n} < 1$ implies convergence; $\limsup a_{n}^{1/n} > 1$ implies divergence; $\limsup a_{n}^{1/n} = 1$ gives no conclusion) conventionally does not use the condition $\liminf a_{n}^{1/n} > 1$ to get rid of the inconclusive part like the generalized ratio test does?

If $\liminf a_{n}^{1/n} = s$ for some $s > 1,$ then, given an $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $s - \varepsilon > 1$, there is an $N \geq 1$ such that
$$a_{n}^{1/n} > s - \varepsilon$$ 
for all $n \geq N.$
Letting $\delta := s - \varepsilon$ gives $\delta > 1$. Since $a_{n} > \delta^{n}$ for all $n \geq N,$ by comparison $\sum a_{n}$ diverges.

Comment: It looks to me like your lim inf > 1 condition does imply divergence, at least for series of positive terms. One drawback to it might be that insertion of an interlaced sequence of 0 terms would make the lim inf 0 for any case in which the lim inf started out > 1, yet the series with the inserted 0 terms has the same convergence/divergence status.

Comment: Another note: Since generally lim inf is <= lim sup, given a series for which your lim inf >1 condition holds, that series will also have lim sup >1 and so be covered by the usual root test as divergent.

Comment: Thanks for interest. Then the problem maybe sometimes things may go wrong when $\liminf$ is considered instead?

Comment: Well not that they go wrong. Only that you would need lim inf > 1 for any conclusion, but then lim sup already >1 and covered by usual root test. So using lim inf doesn't contribute new divergent series. I guess it's clear that lim inf < 1 can give absolutely no conclusion (diverge or converge).

Comment: I was wondering the exact same thing. Why not just use liminf ?